# "between now and then" meaning

Tags: phrase-meaning

A teacher is saying to her students:

> Between now and then, observe yourself. Bring in information. Be committed, constant and fair to each other.

Does it mean "in this time period"? or it means "sometimes"?

Comment: The teacher's instruction doesn't make much sense without further context. What is she referring to?

Comment: She's just giving suggestions about a project to her students, asking them something to do.